# Using router's DNS on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: networking, dns, 22.10

I'm running multiple Ubuntu VMs and would like to refer to them by hostnames when using ssh instead of their IPs. Because I don't want to add every server to every /etc/hosts I thought using DNS aliases would be best.

I setup a VM to run dnsmasq and made some entries of IP to hostnames, along with using 8.8.8.8 as a backup. Then I created a custom DNS config on my router to point to that VM (with 8.8.8.8 as a backup there too).

Machines like my Macbook follow the router's DNS settings and use the VM for lookup, but my other Ubuntu VMs don't. How can I make Ubuntu use my router for DNS?

Comment: Have you rebooted the Unbuntu server (or at least restarted networking)?

Comment: Yes, they've been rebooted with no change to behavior

Comment: What does network-mangler say?  Maybe you need to explicitly tell it what DNS server to use.

Comment: Have you thought about enabling Dynamic DNS on your router?  That will create a DNS entry for the hosts as they get their DHCP created IP address.

Comment: It doesn't look like my router supports dynamic DNS. I think I've determined the issue. systemd-resolved is running using port 53. dnsmasq can't run as well if port 53 is in use, but it also seems like systemd-resolved needs to be running for dnsmasq to run